# Integrate $\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x-x^3)\mathrm dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Is there any way of integrating
$$\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x-x^3)\mathrm dx$$
in closed form?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+cos%28x-x%5E3%29+x%3D0..infinity) gives a closed form in terms of the special Airy function

$$\int_0^\infty \cos(x-x^3)\,\mathrm{d}x =  \frac{\pi}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\text{Ai}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recalling that the [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation:
$$ y''-xy = 0\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$\operatorname{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)\,dt \tag{2}$$
and:
$$\operatorname{Ai}(0)=\frac{1}{3^{\frac{2}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)},\qquad \operatorname{Ai}'(0)=-\frac{1}{3^{\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)},\tag{3}$$
while the Laurent series is given by:
$$\operatorname{Ai}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{3^{\frac{n-2}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}(n+1)\right)}{\pi\cdot n!}\,z^n.\tag{4}$$
By $(2)$ and $(4)$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(x^3-x)\,dx = \pi\, 3^{-\frac{1}{3}}\,\operatorname{Ai}\left(-3^{-1/3}\right) =\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\, \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}(n+1)\right)}{3\,n!}}\tag{5}$$